# Nested loops seem to skip over second loop in Bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to write a script that:

a) reads the content of a .csv file

b) sets a variable to the value in the first position (ie to the left of the comma)

c) compare the variable value to each position in an array. If the value is in the array execute one command, if it isn't, insert that value into the first available slot in the array.

The .csv file is in the format:

> co:7077,he17208am3200816internet.pdf,he17208am3200917internet.pdf
>   co:7077,he17208am3200817internet.pdf,he17208am3200918internet.pdf
>   co:7077,he17208am3200818internet.pdf,he17208am3200919internet.pdf
>   co:7077,he17208am3200819internet.pdf,he17208am3200915internet.pdf
>   co:7162,tra210051internet.pdf,tra21005101internet.pdf
>   co:7162,tra210051appinternet.pdf,tra21005102internet.pdf
>   co:7178,tra4157l11201021internet.pdf,tra4158l11201021internet.pdf
>   co:7178,tra4157l11201022internet.pdf,tra4158l11201022internet.pdf

My script so far looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array
anum=0
src=source.csv
pid=0

while read line;
do
pid=$( echo $line | awk '{print$1}' FS=",")

  for n in "${array[@]}";
     do

        if [[ "$pid" = "$n" ]] ;
         then

          echo Duplicate value: "$pid";

         else
          array[$anum]="$pid"
          anum=$(( $anum +1 ))
        fi
     done
done < $src

echo ${array[@]}
```

When the script is executed the pid is successfully set and reset with each iteration of the while loop, but apparently the nested for loop is never ran.

From my google'ing I suspect it has something to do with the pipe in pid line, but I'll be buggered if I can figure out how to make it work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're not populating your array. The for loop is never executed because the array is empty.

Comment: Shouldn't the "else" populate the array?  If I were to declare the array with some value then you are thinking the for loop would execute?  I shall try that.

Comment: @Tim the "else" is within the for loop and so will never be executed if the array is empty. You need to put something in the array to make it enter the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

why did you use double square brackets? and also you used a single equals rather than double in the if?

try these one-liners...

```
$ if [ "a" == "b" ] ; then echo hello ; fi

$ if [ "a" == "a" ] ; then echo hello ; fi
```

Comment: Double square brackets are valid Bash syntax and provide additional functionality over single ones. In square brackets double and single equal signs are equivalent in Bash. In numeric comparisons using double parentheses, double equal is required.

Comment: To be honest I'm not much of a scripter, I took these lines from examples either online or in other scripts on the system without full understanding of all the subtleties.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag in the `else` clause instead of adding the array element there. After your `for` loop if the flag is set, add the array element. Don't forget to unset the flag.

You can do `array[anum++]` without the next line or `(( anum++ ))` instead of `anum=$(($anum + 1))`.

Also: `while IFS=, read -r pid discard` if you don't need the rest of the line (you could do it a little differently if you need it). Doing this, you won't need the `echo` and `awk`.